# Is there a built-in function to calculate nCr in C++?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++17, built-in

In python 3.8, there is a built-in function for calculating the number of combinations ([nCr(n, k)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)):

```
>>>from math import comb
>>>comb(10,3)
120
```

Is there any such function in C++?

Comment: What are "nCr" and `comb`?

Comment: @NicolBolas Combinatorics. It's a Statistics and Probability thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `beta` function from the mathematical library can be used to express binomial coefficients (aka nCr).

```
double binom(int n, int k) {
    return 1/((n+1)*std::beta(n-k+1,k+1));
}
```

[Source.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/special_functions/beta)

This function is available either with C++17 or as part of an implementation of the mathematical special functions extensions for C++ (ISO/IEC 29124:2010). In the latter case, your implementation may require you  to `#define __STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ 1` before including the `<cmath>` header for the function to be available.

Note that, unlike Python, C++ does not have built-in support for big integer numbers, so using floating point arithmetic is probably a good choice here in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @ComicSansMS,
a quick note is that this is executing in C++17 ONLY.(not in lower versions)
and by defining 
```
#define __STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ 1
```

Comment: @18-051_sumekagarwal Thanks for pointing this out, I extended the answer. The history of the mathematical special functions is somewhat convoluted and I wrongfully assumed familiarity with it when drafting the initial answer.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: If using C++17, use the `beta` function as described by [@ComicSansMS](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67196949/revisions) Otherwise you can use the `tgamma` or even `lgamma` functions if using C++11

Using `lgamma`:

```
double comb_l(double n, double k) {
    return std::exp(std::lgamma(n + 1)- std::lgamma(k + 1) - std::lgamma(n - k + 1));
}
```

Using `tgamma`:

```
double comb_t(double n, double k) {
        return std::tgamma(n + 1) / std::tgamma(k + 1) / std::tgamma(n - k + 1));
}
```